# nth-child selecting wrong child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

For some reason nth-child(1) is not selecting the first p element. But if I put nth-child(2) it selects the first element. I use nth-child quite often and I don't see anything wrong with my code. Can someone explain why this is happening. Thanks

```css
#canvassing_page #canvassing p {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}

#canvassing_page #canvassing p:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<section id="canvassing_page">
  <section id="canvassing">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8">
          <div>
            <h1 class="heading font_blue border_orange">CANVASSING</h1>
          </div>

          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean felis libero, finibus efficitur fermentum quis, facilisis ut lacus. Suspendisse a vehicula elit. Aliquam eu feugiat arcu. Sed justo mauris, sollicitudin molestie fringilla vestibulum,
            egestas in neque. Phasellus nec egestas dolor. Aliquam mollis posuere lacus, et eleifend elit aliquam eget. Integer ut sapien a felis vehicula hendrerit. Nam tortor leo, porta in iaculis at, tempor eu purus. Aenean cursus congue ante. Curabitur
            non convallis libero. Duis fermentum mollis turpis.</p>

          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean felis libero, finibus efficitur fermentum quis, facilisis ut lacus. Suspendisse a vehicula elit. Aliquam eu feugiat arcu. Sed justo mauris, sollicitudin molestie fringilla vestibulum,
            egestas in neque. Phasellus nec egestas dolor. Aliquam mollis posuere lacus, et eleifend elit aliquam eget. Integer ut sapien a felis vehicula hendrerit. Nam tortor leo, porta in iaculis at, tempor eu purus. Aenean cursus congue ante. Curabitur
            non convallis libero. Duis fermentum mollis turpis.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
```

Comment: The div with the title is the first child, not the paragraph.

Comment: But I've selected the paragraph elements so shouldn't it only count them?

Comment: No, CSS selectors work from right to left, so the first child is selected first, then it's checked whether it's a paragraph and so on.

Comment: I've been using selectors for ages and I never knew this. I always figured it would only count the elements that I selected. I'll have to look into this more and educate myself. nth-of-type is what I'm looking for in this situation thank. if you post it as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks

Comment: @Nit No, no. This is not because "CSS selectors work from right to left", but because `p:nth-child(1)` simply means "a p that is also a first child".